# How to load resources in the background?

Tags: multithreading, opengl, loading, glfw

So first things first:

I know that OpenGL does not have a real concept of threaded execution. Creating a "shared context" and giving commands to said shared context does not equal to "things happen in parallel", but at the least I thought that uploading data for a texture would work without much of a hitch. So what I set up is a window class that, upon construction, also constructs a loader (putting all code here for a minimal working example isn't feasable):

Window Members:

```cpp
class Window {
[...]
private:
        GLFWwindow* p_handle;
        GLFWwindow* p_loader_handle;

        const char* p_title;
        
        std::thread loader;

        std::mutex queue_mutex;
        std::condition_variable queue_cv;
        std::queue<Task> task_queue;
```

Window Constructor

```cpp
video::Window::Window(unsigned int width, unsigned int height, const char* title, bool decoration, bool vsync) : loader() {
    
    this->p_title = title;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, decoration);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, true);
    this->p_handle = glfwCreateWindow((int) width, (int) height, title, NULL, NULL);
    if (!p_handle) {
        std::cerr << "Window could not be created. Exiting ..." << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(32);
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(this->p_handle);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, false);
    this->p_loader_handle = glfwCreateWindow(16, 16, "Loader", NULL, this->p_handle);

    if (!p_loader_handle) {
        std::cerr << "Window could not be created. Exiting ..." << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(33);
    }

    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        exit(66);
    }

    this->loader = std::thread(&Window::await_tasks, this);
    [...]
```

The await tasks function:

```cpp
void video::Window::await_tasks() {
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(this->p_loader_handle);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    while (!this->should_close()) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queue_mutex);
        this->queue_cv.wait(lock, [this]() {return this->should_close() || !(this->task_queue.empty()); });
        if (this->should_close()) {
            return;
        }
        Task task = this->task_queue.front();
        this->task_queue.pop();
        lock.unlock();
        task.task(task.data);
    }
}
```

And when I want something to be done in the background I call:

```cpp
void video::Window::task(std::function<void(void*)> task, void *data) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->queue_mutex);
    this->task_queue.emplace(task, data);
    this->queue_cv.notify_one();
}
```

So yeah, this is a basic thread pool implementation with a single thread in the pool.

What the problem is, is that when I now try to load a texture in the background, the resulting images seem to be only partial or not at all uploaded to the GPU.

The code executed e.g. as a task is this, using lodepng as a quick and easy png decoder:

```cpp
void image::read_png(GLuint& width, GLuint& height, GLvoid **data, std::string filename)
{
    std::vector<unsigned char> image_vector;
    unsigned int error = lodepng::decode(image_vector, width, height, filename);
    if (error) {
        std::cerr << "[ERROR] lodepng error: " << error << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "[ERROR] lodepng was unable to load: " << filename << std::endl;
    }

    // std::cout << "[INFO] Image of dimensions " << width << " x " << height << " and a size of " << image_vector.size() << " bytes loaded." << std::endl;

    unsigned char *image_array = new unsigned char[image_vector.size()];
    unsigned char *row;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        row = &image_vector[i * width * 4];
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < width * 4; j++) {
            image_array[j + (height - i - 1) * width * 4] = row[j];
        }
    }

    *data = image_array;
}

openGL::Texture image::load_texture(std::string filename)
{
    GLuint width;
    GLuint height;
    GLvoid *data;
    texture_loader(width, height, &data, filename);
    return openGL::Texture(width, height, data);
}

image::Loader image::texture_loader = image::read_png;
```

Where the constructor of the Texture wrapper is as follows:

```cpp
openGL::Texture::Texture(GLuint width, GLuint height, GLvoid* data)
{
    GLint bound;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, &bound);
    glGenTextures(1, &(this->texture));
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, bound);

    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
}
```

Debugging the internal memory with NVidia NSight results in the same internal data uploaded as can be seen by this test image:

[image: Sample Output]

Yet when I upload the thing on the main Thread and use the same image and same process, I get this:

[image: Expected Output]

I am very much at a loss about what is happening here.

What I want to implement is a smooth loading screen, one that animates while work is being done in the background, not something that is stuttering about as one resource is loaded per frame and then the image is being processed and presented while waiting for larger files to make the loading stutter and break like we are used to for so many years in all kinds of applications and games.

Comment: Due to writing this serving as a good rubber duck my suspicion was as follows: As the image is being cut off bottom to top it seems that the data in my data array becomes suddenly 0. This can only be if the data upload is either interrupted or the data becomes 0. It seems that because the upload happens off-thread, if I force a glFinish(), the error disappears. This leads to my conclusion that the data behind the data pointer gets nulled ... but why? Until now I do not even free the data (yes memory leak ... fixed already) and the task does not end the thread so it shouldnt be nulled.

Comment: Never use glX functions inside a thread. Load/calculate data on a thread but buffer with glX on the main thread. Most modern games still do not have smooth frame loading screens and it's not really a huge issue. I would suggest separating the image loading without buffering to GL into threads in which you update your progress, and the main thread renders, then buffer all the data in the main thread, which won't take as long as the loading.

Comment: That sounds like a ... sad thing ... especially as it feels like shared contexts are made for this ... Do you have any sources about why this is always prone to break? Also about that off-thread loading: Are you sure? Many games even insert minigames or interactibles into their loadingscreens nowadays, those seem to animate at a smooth rate without hiccups.

Comment: I don't want to mislead you, I just avoid GL calls in my threads because it mentioned it on the docs somewhere to not do so, and maybe doesn't apply to shared context. I do most of my texture load/buffer on the main thread before the main render loop, and the hundreds of buffer calls during render loop (geometric not texture) have no lag at all. It's one of those things where you should only optimize/parallelize if your profiler indicates it  should be.